# Cache Graph for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rubygems

Do you know any Ruby gem or library that implements cache with dependency graph? I'm looking for a solution for organizing cache objects to a graph structure and it's intelligent enough to invalidate all the dependencies of a node recursively when the node becomes invalid. It's just better if it supports Memcached or Redis as a storage engine.

Comment: What will be the case when node will become invalid?

Comment: When a node becomes invalid then all of its descendants would become invalid. Let me give you an example. There is a `user-12` node that is a cache node for `user#12`. This parent node does not store data. It has subnodes for the attributes, `user-12-name`, `user-12-email`,... Only the leaves store data. When `user#12`'s email address is updated then only cache `user-12-email` would be invalidated but the others would remain active. When the user is being deleted then the parent node (`user-12`) would become invalid and all of its dependencies, so `user-12-name`, `user-12-email`.